# SWT KeyEvent bug or design miss the release event completely

Tags: java, events, swt

Copy the code below in your IDE. I tested that code with Windows 10, Java 8.

Press 2 keys say A (first) and B (second) and release the first key pressed before quickly releasing the second key pressed. The release event for the second key pressed is lost.

If you keep the second key pressed, it will start generating key repetition again and then the key release is caught.

This event disappearing actually screw up the code because it cannot account for the missed release event and the state is screwed. This bug is a disgrace!! Worse than AWT Linux Key event bug which I found a decent fix for.

Do you see a solution? Can you disable key repetition in SWT (Maybe)?

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SWTKeyEvent {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell(display);
  shell.setText("SWT KeyEvent Example");

  shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

  Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.CENTER);

  button.setText("Type Something");

  button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        boolean isKeyRepeat = isKeyRepeat(e.keyCode);
        if (!isKeyRepeat) {
           System.out.println("\t keyPressed " + e.keyCode);
        } else {
           System.out.println("keyRepeated " + e.keyCode);
        }
     }

     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("\t\t keyReleased " + e.keyCode);
        keyReleaseRepeat(e.keyCode);
     }

  });

  shell.open();

  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
     if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
 }

protected static int   pressedKeyCounter;

protected static int[] pressedKeys = new int[20];



public static boolean isKeyRepeat(int keyCode) {
  for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeyCounter; i++) {
     if (pressedKeys[i] == keyCode) {
        return true;
     }
  }
  pressedKeys[pressedKeyCounter] = keyCode;
  pressedKeyCounter++;
  return false;
}


public static void keyReleaseRepeat(int keyCode) {
  boolean shift = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < pressedKeyCounter; i++) {
     if (pressedKeys[i] == keyCode) {
        shift = true;
     } else if (shift) {
        pressedKeys[i - 1] = pressedKeys[i];
     }
  }
  if (pressedKeyCounter > 0) {
     pressedKeyCounter--;
  }
}
```

EDIT: In Swing or JavaFX, the release event is NEVER lost

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: @Baz a gaming framework compatible with SWT. I will use JInput to go around this bug. and use the Linux bug technique (drop event too close togethere) to get around things

Comment: What I meant was: You posted a code example and instructions to reproduce a certain (unwanted) behaviour. I'd like to know though: What is it that your application is supposed to do specifically and how does the code you've got differ from that. It's got something to do with repeated key strokes is as much as I gathered.

Comment: @Baz I absolutely need the release event!!! Otherwise the game engine thinks the key is pressed!!!!! Like Up and Left keys are pressed at the same time. Release Up and then Left... Left key is still pressed state for the engine. I don't want repeat events actually. I drop them. In Swing it works pretty well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. I can't help you. Also, one exclamation mark is sufficient.